# How to extract text from a two-column PDF using PDFPlumber

Tags: python, text-extraction, topic-modeling, information-extraction, pdfplumber

I am working on topic modeling tasks using python and I would like to extract texts from annual/sustainability reports. However my problem is, when I tried to extract the report, the extracted lines are broken between two different columns in a page i.e., it joins two different lines from neighbouring paragraph to make a sentence. How do I extract the  lines exactly the way it is present in the report. I have attached the version of the report and the lines extracted by the function.

Below is the function that I use:

**#function to obtain the pdf from a url**:

```py
def converter(url):
    text=[]
    req= requests.get(url)
    with pdfplumber.open(BytesIO(req.content)) as pdf:
        for i in range(0, len(pdf.pages)):
            pages= pdf.pages[i]
            text.append(pages.extract_text())
    return "\n".join(str(i) for i in text)
```

[The image is a snippet from the report I am extracting, the text in the report is divided into two columns and the extract_content function mixes up these two columns to get a line, i.e., joins lines in two columns and presents as a single line.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q05el.png)

Here is the first line of the report (starting of the first column and second column merged together by the function):

> \nOne of my first duties in 2019 was an **interview  When** we
> embarked on a new strategy period \non the “Good Morning Norway” show
> to talk  in 2016, I expressed a hope that AF would feel \nabout AF’s
> goal of doubling the percentage of  just as close-knit when we
> hopefully surpass \nwomen

It would be helpful if I can extract the sentences in the exact way given in report.

Answer (score 6):

This is based on a [response by samkit-jain](https://github.com/jsvine/pdfplumber/issues/244#issuecomment-670585479) to an issue on the package.

The key is `page.crop`

Assuming there is no header information, crop the page into two halves:

```
left = page.crop((0, 0, 0.5 * page.width, 0.9 * page.height))
right = page.crop((0.5 * page.width, 0, page.width, page.height)
```

Then extract text and concatenate:

```
l_text = left.extract_text()
r_text = right.extract_text()
text = l_text + " " + r_text
```

Of course, if a page on your report has a figure that spans both columns, that will be messed up by this approach, so you may have to customize this per page.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: How might I do this **conditionally**? Only if when a page does have column text @Kaia