# Scraping a sentence across many lines | Recursive error unresolved

Tags: python, recursion, pypdf, pdfplumber

Goal: if pdf line contains sub-string, then copy entire sentence (across multiple lines).

I am able to `print()` the `line` the `phrase` appears in.

Now, once I find this `line`, I want to go back iterations, until I find a sentence terminator: `. ! ?`, from the previous sentence, and iterate forward again until the next sentence terminator.

This is so as I can `print()` the entire sentence the phrase belongs in.

However, I have a Recursive Error with `scrape_sentence()` getting stuck infinitely running.

---

**Jupyter Notebook:**

```py
# pip install PyPDF2
# pip install pdfplumber

# ---
# import re
import glob
import PyPDF2
import pdfplumber

# ---
phrase = "Responsible Care Company"
# SENTENCE_REGEX = re.pattern('^[A-Z][^?!.]*[?.!]$')

def scrape_sentence(sentence, lines, index, phrase):
    if '.' in lines[index] or '!' in lines[index] or '?' in lines[index]:
        return sentence.replace('\n', '').strip()
    sentence = scrape_sentence(lines[index-1] + sentence, lines, index-1, phrase)  # previous line
    sentence = scrape_sentence(sentence + lines[index+1], lines, index+1, phrase)  # following line    
    
    sentence = sentence.replace('!', '.')
    sentence = sentence.replace('?', '.')
    sentence = sentence.split('.')
    sentence = [s for s in sentence if phrase in s]
    sentence = sentence[0]  # first occurance
    print(sentence)
    
    return sentence
    
# ---    
    
with pdfplumber.open('../data/gri/reports/GPIC_Sustainability_Report_2020__-_40_Years_of_Sustainable_Success.pdf') as opened_pdf:
    for page in opened_pdf.pages:
        text = page.extract_text()
        lines = text.split('\n')
        i = 0
        sentence = ''
        while i < len(lines):
            if 'and Knowledge of Individuals; Behaviours; Attitudes, Perception ' in lines[i]:
                sentence = scrape_sentence('', lines, i)  # !
                print(sentence)  # !
            i += 1
```

**Output:**

```
connection and the linkage to the relevant UN’s 17 SDGs.and Leadership. We have long realized and recognized that there
```

---

Phrase:

```
Responsible Care Company
```

Sentence (across multiple lines):

```
"GPIC is a Responsible Care Company certified for RC 14001 
since July 2010."
```

[PDF (pg. 2)](https://ungc-production.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/attachments/cop_2016/290831/original/GPIC_Sustainability_Report_2016-v9_%28lr%29.pdf?1465251381).

---

Please let me know if there is anything else I can add to post.

Comment: Related post https://stackoverflow.com/q/68919080/16105404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70167466/16105404) by removing any recursion from `scrape_sentence()`.